Finding a basis of relative homology group $H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$ .
I am trying to solve a problem from the Homology theory chapter of Hatcher's book.The problem is the following:

Show that the relative homology group $H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$ is free abelian and find its basis.

I think I have done the first part of the problem that is to show that the homology is free abelian.Considering $X=\mathbb R,A=\mathbb Q$ we consider the pair $(X,A)=(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$.So we have a long exact sequence for this pair which is as follows:
$\dots \to H_1(\mathbb Q)\to H_1(\mathbb R)\to H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)\to \tilde H_0(\mathbb Q)\to \tilde H_0(\mathbb R)\to \tilde H_0(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)\to 0$
Since $\mathbb R$ is contractible,so its $H_1(\mathbb R)=\tilde H_0(\mathbb R)=0$ and this ensures that $H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)\simeq \tilde H_0(\mathbb Q)$.Now $\tilde H_0(\mathbb Q)=\bigoplus_{n} \mathbb Z$ since $\mathbb Q$ is having countably infinite number of path components and hence its $0$-th homology has countably infinite copies of $\mathbb Z$ and the reduced homology at $0$-level has one copy less,but it is again countably infinite number of copies of $\mathbb Z$.
Now the next question is to find the generators of $H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$.I don't know how to do that,maybe we can just pull back the generators of $\tilde H_0(\mathbb Q)$ using the connecting homomorphism $\partial_*:H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)\to \tilde H_0(\mathbb Q)$.
But for that I have to write explicitly what the connecting homomorphism is.That seems a bit tough.Can someone tell me if I am in the right direction?

This is not as bad as it sounds. The elements of $H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$ are sums of $1$-simplices in $\mathbb{R}$ with endpoints in $\mathbb{Q}$ and the boundary of a $1$-simplex is the formal difference of its endpoints. I think working with unreduced homology in the $0$-terms is slightly more accessible here, but the difference isn't much.

@Thorgott You meant $Z_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb  Q)$ right? the relative $1$-cycles and not the homology $H_1(\mathbb R,\mathbb Q)$ I guess?

Consider the long exact sequence
$$\cdots\to H_1(\mathbb{R})\to H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})\xrightarrow{\partial}H_0(\mathbb{Q})\xrightarrow{i_0} H_0(\mathbb{R})\to \cdots.$$
Note that $H_1(\mathbb{R})=0,H_0(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{Z},H_0(\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Q})}$(the connected components of $\mathbb{Q}$ are single points), $i_0(e_i)=1$ where $e_i$ refers to elements in $\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Q})}$ with $i'th$ component equals to 1. So $$H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathrm{Im}\partial=\ker(i_0:\mathbb{Z}^{(\mathbb{Q})}\to\mathbb{Z})=\{\sum_{<\infty}a_{i}e_i|\sum a_i=0\}$$ is a free abelian group generated by $\{e_i-e_0\}_{i\in\mathbb{Z}}$. Let $f_a:\Delta_0\to\mathbb{Q},x\mapsto a\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then the basis $\{[f_a-f_0]\}_{a\in\mathbb{Q}}$ generates $\ker i_0$. By the construction of $\partial,\partial([\alpha])=[\partial\alpha]$, so the corresponding generators of $H_1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$ are $\partial^{-1}([f_a-f_0])=[F_a]$ where $F_a:\Delta_1\to\mathbb{R}$ is a path from $0$ to $a$.
